# Difference between member and shareholder of a residential management company in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, real-estate, limited-liability-company

My wife and I are joint lessees of a flat within a block, in the UK.  There is a management company responsible for managing the common areas within the block.  The lease requires the lessee to apply to become a member of the management company.  The management company is a private company limited by shares.

*Question* Is being a member of the company the same as being a shareholder, and if not what is the difference?

Comment: A shareholder normally has to purchase shares. Members do not.The rights of shareholders and of members should be set out in the Company's [Memorandum and articles of association](https://www.gov.uk/limited-company-formation/memorandum-and-articles-of-association) which are available from Companies House.

Answer (score 1):

(Answering my own question following further research.)

Yes, for a UK company limited by shares, being a member and being a shareholder are one and the same.  This is stated or implied by numerous websites including the following: [1st Formations Limited](https://www.1stformations.co.uk/shares-and-shareholders/); [Company Law Club](https://www.companylawclub.co.uk/what-is-the-difference-between-shareholders-and-directors); [UK Business Forums](https://www.ukbusinessforums.co.uk/threads/company-member-definition.41884/); [Inform Direct](https://www.informdirect.co.uk/company-records/register-of-members/).

It's worth noting however that not all UK companies are limited by shares.  Some, typically non-profit organisations, are [limited by guarantee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_company_limited_by_guarantee), having members but often no share capital and therefore no shareholders.